# Null token return true in if condition

Tags: express

[image]

Losing my mind over this as it stops me from doing something else. When the request supplies an empty token (e.g. 'Bearer '). It's null after the split but the condition returns true

Comment: Print out `bearer`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
a=null
console.log(typeof(a))
if(a){
  console.log("hello")
}
//output
//object
```

This won't print "hello" because js treats null ,undefined ,false,Nan and "" as 0.
But in your case if

```
a="null"
console.log(typeof(a))
if(a){
  console.log("hello")
}
//This will print 
// string
// hello
```